# PHPExcel - error while trying to insert image after loading and writing

Tags: php, image, append, phpexcel

i saw this problem in so many posts. but none have been answered. 
first time when I insert image in an excel file, no problem is there.but if i load that excel file again and try to insert another image in another cell,following problem occurs:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PHPExcel_Writer_Exception' with message 'File zip://C:\xampp\htdocs\Well\test.xlsx#xl/media/well1.bmp does not exist' in C:\xampp\htdocs\Well\Classes\PHPExcel\Writer\Excel2007\ContentTypes.php:242 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Well\Classes\PHPExcel\Writer\Excel2007\ContentTypes.php(181): PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007_ContentTypes->_getImageMimeType('zip://C:\xampp\...') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\Well\Classes\PHPExcel\Writer\Excel2007.php(246): PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007_ContentTypes->writeContentTypes(Object(PHPExcel), false) #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\Well\test.php(125): PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007->save('test.xlsx') #3 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Well\Classes\PHPExcel\Writer\Excel2007\ContentTypes.php on line 242.
```

This is my code to draw:

```
`$objDrawing = new PHPExcel_Worksheet_Drawing();
$objDrawing->setName('image');
$objDrawing->setDescription('nnnnn');
$objDrawing->setPath('images/well.bmp');
$objDrawing->setCoordinates('I'.$s);
$objDrawing->setWorksheet($objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet());`
```

I searched  lot and I saw some posts regarding it. but none of them have been answered.

Edit:
My code:

```
require_once 'Classes/PHPExcel.php';
require_once 'Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';
$name='statistics.xlsx';
if(file_exists($name))
{
 $objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($name);
 $lastRow = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getHighestRow();
 $j=$lastRow+10;
}
else
{
 $j=1;
 $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
 }
 $i='A';

 $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

// I am not writing the entire data

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($i++.$j, 'name');

$objDrawing = new PHPExcel_Worksheet_Drawing();
$objDrawing->setName('image');
$objDrawing->setDescription('image');
$objDrawing->setPath('image.png');
$objDrawing->setCoordinates('E'.$s);
$objDrawing->setWorksheet($objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet());

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
$objWriter->save($name);
```

Comment: Could you please post your whole code with detailed instruction how to replicate this error?

Comment: @Grzegorz...Thanks for the reply. I have included the entire code. Please check it. No problem while saving for first time. But when I try for 2nd time,its showing the error and it deletes the saved file. Please look into it.

Answer (score 8):

I think this is a bug in PHPExcel in `Classes\PHPExcel\Writer\Excel2007.php`. Its easy to fix.

**Short answer is:** comment out or remove lines 235-237. That would be this code:

```
        if (file_exists($pFilename)) {
            unlink($pFilename);
        }
```

Your code will work then. I've checked, it works for me now.

**Now, some longer explanation.** On lines 235-243 there is this code:

```
        if (file_exists($pFilename)) {
            unlink($pFilename);
        }
        // Try opening the ZIP file
        if ($objZip->open($pFilename, $zipOverWrite) !== true) {
            if ($objZip->open($pFilename, $zipCreate) !== true) {
                throw new PHPExcel_Writer_Exception("Could not open " . $pFilename . " for writing.");
            }
        }
```

Now, in this code, three things take place in order:

1. If we're saving data to existing file, then this file is deleted (`unlink`)
2. If we're saving data to existing file, overwrite this file
3. If we're saving data to non-existing file, create it

As you see, operation from step 2 is never executed because in step 1 file is *always* deleted. And in this process all previously existing file attachments are lost. That's why later you get error `File XXX does not exist` - indeed, your earlier image files are not present in newly created file.

Obvious fix to this problem is to remove step 1. If file exists, it should be overwritten. I do not see any logical explanation for step 1. Maybe its a left over from some old code.