# Storing images in Excel sheet using PHPExcel in a loop

Tags: phpexcel

I'm trying to save images in an Excel file using PHPExcel. This is part of code -

```
for($i=0; $i< $count; $i++)
{   
        $objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load("file.xlsx");        
        // Code generates url (of the image) corresponding to this iteration of the loop and saves it in the variable $url. $string is the name of the image to be saved.
        file_put_contents('photos/'.$string.'.jpg', file_get_contents($url));
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('B')->setWidth(22);
        $gdImage = imagecreatefromjpeg($url);
        $objDrawing = new PHPExcel_Worksheet_MemoryDrawing();
        $objDrawing->setImageResource($gdImage);
        $objDrawing->setRenderingFunction(PHPExcel_Worksheet_MemoryDrawing::RENDERING_JPEG);
        $objDrawing->setMimeType(PHPExcel_Worksheet_MemoryDrawing::MIMETYPE_DEFAULT);
        $objDrawing->setHeight(150);
        $objDrawing->setWorksheet($objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet());
        $objDrawing->setCoordinates('B'.$i);
        $objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007($objPHPExcel);
        $objWriter->save('file.xlsx');
    }
```

The loop executes once but in the second iteration it generates the following error -

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PHPExcel_Writer_Exception' with message 'File zip:///Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/webscraping/file.xlsx#xl/media/ca8687837091b28ca7245ec6b0b5be751.png does not exist' in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/webscraping/Classes/PHPExcel/Writer/Excel2007/ContentTypes.php:195 Stack trace: #0

How do I remove this error?

Comment: I don't know if it's causing the error, but why on earth are you saving to file each iteration? That's hopelessly inefficient! Why not open the file before the loop, and save after the loop?

Comment: I'm saving to file in each iteration because the amount of information to be stored in each row is huge (apart from the image) and it exhausts memory if I store all the required information in all rows in array and then save to the file after the loop. Therefore, I gather the information in a particular row and write it to the file one row at a time.

Comment: If the amount of information in each row is huge, then it's even less efficient to keep reloading and resaving in every iteration.... because you have to load and save that huge amount of information in every iteration.... I'm not suggesting that you store anything in an array; just work within the PHPExcel object

Comment: What do you suggest then, how should I add the information to the excel sheet without exhausting the memory and loading and saving it only once?

Comment: I've told you.... open the file ___before___ your loop, save it ___after___ your loop

Comment: Has this been solved.. cause i have this same issue, except im loading a file with images already in it, then trying to save it..

Comment: I think this is the bug (currently non-fixed) in PHPExcel, that was nicely explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23951597/261332.

You can see the original code in here: https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/1c8c2379ccf5ab9dd7cb46be965821d22173bcf4/Classes/PHPExcel/Writer/Excel2007.php#L228